# How to maximise and minimise divs on click in jquerymobile

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I ve just started working with jQuerymobile,I got a scenario where I ve places divs like icons in a menu,on clicking the divs it should expand width wise 100% occupying the row in which it's placed,pushing other divs downwards,and later on clicking the now expanded div it should maximise and occupy the full screen.There is also be a provision to minimise back to initial state.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".btn-minimize").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('btn-plus');
    $(".widget-content").slideToggle();
  });
```

**[fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/uzmjq/210/)**

Comment: thanks vaibs_cool,but it's not exactly what i want.I have edited my query ,added more detail

Comment: @Ajith Give ur html markup or edit my fiddle with your markup